# Why xs ++ acc works when using foldr on an infinite list, but acc ++ xs doesn't?

Tags: haskell, fold

*I know the question title might be misleading, because I'm not concatenating an infinite list with anything here. Feel free to propose something more suitable.*

Here is a working implementation of the `cycle` function from `Prelude` using `foldr`:

```
fold_cycle :: [a] -> [a]
fold_cycle xs = foldr step [] [1..]
    where step x acc = xs ++ acc
```

If we switch the operands of `++` to `acc ++ xs`, this function no longer works. It produces a stack overflow, which, by my understanding, is the result of trying to produce a never-ending expression for later evaluation.

I have trouble understanding what is the reason behind this. My reasoning is that regardless of the order of operands, `foldr` should evaluate `step` once, produce the new accumulator and proceed to evaluate the `step` function again if necessary. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foldr` doesn't evaluate the accumulator at all if it's not forced. `fold_cycle` works precisely because it doesn't necessarily evaluate `acc`.

```
fold_cycle [1, 2]
```

reduces to

```
[1, 2] ++ ([1, 2] ++ ([1, 2] ++ ([1, 2] ++ ...
```

Which allows us to evaluate prefixes of the result because `++` lets us traverse the first argument without evaluating the second.

If we use `step _ acc = acc ++ xs`, the parentheses in the above expression associate to the left instead of right. But since we have an infinite number of appends, the expression ends up like this:

```
((((((((((((((... -- parentheses all the way down
```

Intuitively, we would have to step over an infinite number of parentheses to inspect the first element of the resulting list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a wrong impression how `foldr` actually works. I thought that the accumulator really accumulates something, not that its initial value is used inside each application of `foldr`. Reading how it is implemented helped. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, so I accept it.